# What is the meaning of ". ." in a mathematical formula?

Tags: notation

I was looking for some Final Fantasy Tactics info on Arqade. I found [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/76528/253858) that, in turn, cites [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197339-final-fantasy-tactics/faqs/3876).
The guide features the formula:

```
enemy level = ((HiLv - [HiLv/8]) .. HiLv)
```

It told me what I wanted to know about the game's mechanics. I don't need anything further on that.
The problem is this ". ." in the formula. I've never seen this before.
I figured it was probably standard computer/internet notation for a common maths operation, but it wasn't on any lists, cheat sheets etc. I found.

Does anyone know the meaning of this notation?
I don't even care about the game anymore. This is driving me crazy. >.<

P.S.: it doesn't help that internet search fields don't play well with punctuation signs. It's actually kinda hard to search for "..", with or without quotations. =|

Comment: Try reading section 1.2 of the guide you linked.

Comment: I understand why you'd think this is a mathematics question, but it isn't.

Comment: They are talking about *randomly chosen* enemy level, so I guess `..` is meant to denote a *range* of possible values (from `HiLv - [HiLv/8]` to `HiLv`). It is not a mathematical symbol, and most likely comes from some programming language. (Pascal comes to mind.) And yes, this is mentioned in section 1.2.

Comment: @StinkingBishop It's a notation promoted by Don Knuth in his TAOCP, where he offers it up as a superior notation to $[a, b]$ or $(a, b)$ etc. to specify (respectively) a closed and open interval of a totally ordered set (usually the reals). IMO this notation is a lot better than the ones it is attempting to supplant.

Comment: @LewisMacRae Thanks! It never occurred to me that the guide itself might explain it. I just assumed it was standard notation that I wasn't familiar with.

Comment: @GitGud Why? There's even a specific tag for notation questions.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Very interesting! Knuth is such an amazing scholar. I really wanted to read TAoCP, but I fear it would be too much for a layman in computer science.

Comment: @denismattos It's not a mathematical notation. It's a notation that some guy decided to use in an arithmetical expression. It's not standardized.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, but, considering it appeared in a formula and I didn't know it, how was I supposed to know, beforehand, that it wasn't a mathematical notation that I hadn't encountered before?

Comment: I guess you wouldn't. My [previous comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427360/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-mathematical-formula?noredirect=1#comment9265668_4427360) supports this. And it also served to let you know it's not a mathematics question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by Lewis MacRae is spot on, under section 1.2 - "RANDOM NUMBER GENERATION" they state:

> (x..y) means that the game generates a pseudo-random integer between x
> and y, inclusive. I say 'pseudo' because no PSX random number
> generator is completely random, ...

In other words, given some range from x to y, the game will "randomly" select some integer, i, such that

`x <= i <= y`.

so in the example you gave:

```
enemy level = ((HiLv - [HiLv/8]) .. HiLv)
```

They pick a random enemy level between ($HiLv - \frac{HiLv}{8}$) and $HiLv$

Comment: Thanks for the attention!  
Concise and clear answer. =)